# Handling an XMLHttpRequest with app.post (node.js + express) (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

Context: I'm trying to build a filter functionality with checkboxes. The idea is make the HTML for the checkbox trigger a script, that sends DOM data to the server.

HTML:

```
     <div class="container-modal-1-item-1">

      <label class="checkboxContainer"><input name="checkboxOne" type="checkbox" onchange="filterWords(this)"><span class="checkmark"></span>People</label>

    </div>
```

Script:

```
function filterWords(){

  if(document.getElementsByName('checkboxOne')[0].checked){
    console.log("Is Checked");
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    // open a POST request

    var data = document.getElementsByClassName('checkboxContainer')[0].textContent;
    xhr.open("POST", "/filter", true);
    console.log(data);
    xhr.send(data);
  } else {
    console.log("Is Not Checked");

  }
}
```

Server:

```
app.post("/filter", function(req, res){

  console.log(data);

  res.redirect("/");
})
```

Conclusion/Problem:

The pertinent variable to me is "data". On the first "console.log(data)" I'm correctly getting "People", but how do I get that on the server, after the XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

It’s an easy fix
If I understood what are you trying to do

So you want the data sent by the client

```
app.post("/filter", function(req, res){

  console.log(req.body.data);

  res.redirect("/");
})
```

req.body.data Object has the body sent by a client